# Can someone help me with my homework - Implementation of findMedian(…)

Tags: java

### Problem

I have a task that reads as follows:

Implement an IntegerList class with a Vector  list object attribute that contains a collection of integers. Implement the findMedian () method which, for a given object from o of the IntegerList class, returns a number m from the vector o.list such that there are at least half of the numbers less than or equal to m, and the numbers greater than or equal to m are also at least half:

For example, for [1, 4, 1, 3, 5, 7] it will be the number 4, and for [1, 1, 1, 2, 2] it will be the number 1 and only 1. If the vector is empty then the method is supposed to throw an IllegalArgumentException exception.

### What I tried?

```
import java.util.Vector;    
public class IntegerList {  
    Vector<Integer> list =new Vector<Integer>();    
        
    public int findMedian(Vector<Integer>list){ 
       if(list.size() ==0){ 
           throw new IllegalArgumentException();    
       }    
        int result =0;  
    
    return result;  
    }   
}   
    
    
public class Main { 
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        IntegerList v = new IntegerList();  
        v.list.add(2);  
        v.list.add(3);  
        v.list.add(4);  
        v.list.add(9);  
        System.out.println(v.findMedian(v.list));   
    
    
    }   
}
```

### My question:

Why this not working?
What would you change to even better solve this problem?

Comment: Your findMedian() method doesn't do anything. It always returns 0. You need to do stuff there.

Comment: If you're not sure what to do in code, write it out in English. It's much easier to go from pseudocode to code than it is to go from idea to code

Comment: By the way, `Vector` is barely used nowadays, in favor of `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working, but only on empty list. To make it work: we should apply what we learned ..and little try.

Voila:

```
public int findMedian(Vector<Integer> list) { 
   if (list == null || list.isEmpty()) { 
       throw new IllegalArgumentException("'list' is null or empty");    
   } // from here: list not null and list.size() > 0 ... :
   // sort the "list":    
   java.util.Collections.sort(list); // if you may not modify the list: create a copy first! (the list remains sorted, also when leaving the method...
   // return "middle" element:
   return list.get(list.size()/2); 
}
```

[javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html)